# Microsoft Access 2010 Navigation Pane Font

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to change the font size of the navigation pane in Access 2010.  I don't see any settings to change the font of the items in the Navigation Pane.

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the [new Entry] -> put in text (like: "Button 0")
- Select the Button you have just created
- In the Properties Window change FontSize and height
- Select the navigation control and set the height

Comment: that has nothing to do with the question